# Difference between C pointer declarations

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

What is the difference between these declarations?

Which one of the following is correct and why is that method correct?

```
int val;
int *ptr = val; // first method
int *ptr_2 = &val; // second method
```

Comment: The `int *ptr = val;` requires a diagnostic from your compiler. If you compiler does not complain, I suggest you stop using that one and select a better compiler.

Comment: The compiler sends a casting error @pmg

Comment: Ah! Good nice compiler :) Always pay attention to compiler diagnostics!

Comment: If you're on an embedded system, on a free-standing environment, working on bare metal, ..., (where you happen to know you can use an `int` to store an address) you can correctly and safely use the first option with a cast: `int address = 0xDEADBEEF /* bare metal */; int *ptr = (int*)address;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *ptr_2 = &val;
```

is correct.

The first part (`int *ptr_2`) creates a pointer to an `int`.

The second part (`&val`) returns the address of the variable `val`.

```
int *ptr = val;
```

would assign the **value** of `val` to `ptr2`.

Technically, the first one may work (the compiler might shows a warning or a casting error, see the comments). If an address is stored as an integer in `val`, that address could be used that way but it would make little to no sense to store an address in an `int`.

Also note that `val` will contain a random value(actually what was in that point of the RAM) if you don't initialize it.

Comment: @NisanAbeywickrama as I've edited my question: `int *ptr = val;` would assign the value of val to ptr2.

Comment: Technically, the first is incorrect — regardless of whether a pointer fits inside an `int`.

Comment: @NisanAbeywickrama: You’re attempting to initialize an object of type `int *` with a value of type `int`.  Those types are not *compatible*, so the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic.  If you *cast* the value of `val` to `int *` like: `int *ptr = (int *) val;`, then that will suppress the diagnostic, but your code may not behave as intended.

Comment: @dan1st -- `int *ptr = val;` isn't "kind of correct", it is just incorrect. It is a _constraint violation_ requiring a compiler diagnostic (which may be a warning or an error, the Standard does not care which).

Answer (score 1):

> why is the first method wrong?

I'm not sure what you want to do but the first method is probably **not doing what you expect**.

Therefore, the compiler will give you a warning message unless you write the first method like this:

```
int * ptr = (int *)val;
```

Doing so you tell the compiler that you know what you are doing and you want the compiler to behave as the "first method" behaves.

As user "pmg" wrote in his comment, the "first method" may be useful if you directly access hardware such as in microcontroller programming or when developing an operating system.

> What is the difference of these declarations?

Let's make the program a bit more complicated to see what is happening:

```
int val;
int hello;
int world;
int *ptr1;
int *ptr2;
int *ptr3;
int *ptr4;
int *ptr5;
int *ptr6;

val = (int)&hello; // line "1"
ptr1 = &val; // second method
ptr2 = val;  // first method (1)

val = (int)&world; // line "2"
ptr3 = &val; // second method
ptr4 = val;  // first method (2)

val = 0;
ptr5 = &val; // second method
ptr6 = val;  // first method (2)
```

The "`=`" operator copies the value on the right side into the variable on the left side.

`&val` means: "A pointer to the variable `val`".

Therefore the pointer to the variable `val` will be copied into the variables `ptr1`, `ptr3` and `ptr5` and these three pointer variables will point to the variable `val`.

The value of the variable `val` does not matter in this case.

`val` however means: "The **value** of the variable `val`".

If we are using a 32-bit Windows or Linux operating system, we have written the address of the variable `hello` to the variable `val` in the line marked as "line 1".

The value of `val` is copied to `ptr2` in the line marked as "first method (1)", so `ptr2` contains a pointer to `hello` and **not** a pointer to `val`.

And of course the value of `val` **does** matter:

The variable `ptr4` will contain a pointer to the variable `world` and the variable `ptr6` will have the value `NULL`.

Using a 64-bit Windows or Linux operating system, `ptr2` and `ptr4` may even have *invalid* values in the example above.